# Share notes with other people on a mac

Tags: macos, mac

I am writing a note on my mac. I want to share this note with other people on my mac.

this means specific users on my mac should be able to read and write to this note.

how can I do this?

Comment: Using the **Notes** app?

Comment: yes on mac book pro

Comment: It does not appear to be possible with the stock app. Evernote may be an option. A simple text file on a shared folder may work also.

Comment: I tried evernote and its really lame. Sharing just means sending an email. when other person opens their evernote app, they don't see the shared note.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch it may be a premium feature: https://evernote.com/contact/support/kb/#!/article/24973036?noredirect

Comment: I tried microsoft one note and I got exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is go to your home folder, press "command + up" and open the Shared folder. This folder is fully accessible to all users. The files themselves though need to be made readable and writable to everyone. You can do this by right clicking on the file and opening "Get Info", scrolling to the bottom and changing permissions till they're how you'd like them. You can add users to the list for more fine-grained permission control, or just allow everyone to read and write it for simplicity.

EDIT: Sorry, I'm crazy tired. Some of the original post wasn't true...

Comment: don't worry. microsoft onenote just worked out fine for me.

Comment: Ah. Good to hear!